# When creating a bootable USB drive with Tuxboot, error "the file does not have a program association with it for performing this action"

Tags: windows-7

I was creating a bootable USB flash drive (of GParted) using Tuxboot on my Windows 7 x64 computer. I kept receiving the error during the "installing bootloader" phase: the file does not have a program association with it for performing this action. The USB drive would not boot either, and I would get an error that "bootmgr is missing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a recommendation to run Tuxboot as administrator, which did not help me (but maybe it will help you).

I resolved the "bootmgr is missing" error by formatting the flash drive as FAT32 and then running Tuxboot again. I still received the error message, but my recovery drive was created successfully.

Comment: For reference: as mentioned in this answer on Windows 7 it is required to run as administrator, also stated here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tuxboot/discussion/general/thread/ee36975e/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution for image created thanks to GParted. However, this problem is common with a disk image created using CloneZilla. With Clonezilla the image can be generated in two possible format : .iso or .zip.

You can avoid having this problem using the .iso file format instead of the .zip/.tar format.